# Tailwind CSS & Alpine JS opacity-slide-in transition

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

Hello dear amazing people, I am using Tailwind (CSS) and Alpine (JS) to create a multi-step form. And I want to create a transition for each step change.

I  want the transition to be something simple yet nice, so I decided to do the following:

- Have a container for all steps (individual screens/slides)
- When moving from one step to the other, the transition should be:

  1. Step A fades out (opacity goes from 100 to 0)
  2. Step B slides in (margin left goes from `-ml-5` to `ml-0`) while it fades in (opacity 0 --> 100)

According to the documentation for [Alpine transition](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/transition), it shall be done as follows:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" x-data="{ activeSlide: 1, slides: [1, 2, 3] }">
    <div class="relative" style="height:200px;">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="absolute" style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:blue;" x-show="activeSlide === 1" 
             x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:enter-start="-ml-5 opacity-0"
             x-transition:enter-end="ml-0 opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
            Slide 1
        </div>
        <div class="absolute" style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:orange;" x-show="activeSlide === 2"
             x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:enter-start="-ml-5 opacity-0"
             x-transition:enter-end="ml-0 opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
            Slide 2
        </div>
        <div class="absolute" style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:green;" x-show="activeSlide === 3"
             x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:enter-start="-ml-5 opacity-0"
             x-transition:enter-end="ml-0 opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
            Slide 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Prev/Next arrow buttons -->
    <div class="box flex flex-space-between flex-middle">
        <button x-on:click="activeSlide = activeSlide === 1 ? slides.length : activeSlide - 1">←</button>
        <button x-on:click="activeSlide = activeSlide === slides.length ? 1 : activeSlide + 1">→</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I don't get the slide effect to happen. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: increase duration

Comment: Tailwind [has not](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-duration) `duration-2000` class. You may configure it in `tailwind.config.js` or write class as `duration-[2000ms]`

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka - Thanks, I updated it to duration-1000 (which tailwind does have) and it still does not work. Any idea?

Comment: @ÁlvaroFranz it's working fine on my end here -> https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-tereshkova-mc3nmc?file=/index.html

Comment: @KarimTarek Thanks but it's not. The slide effect is not working. Opacity yes, slide not.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, using margins for moving parts seem to never work as expected. Therefore I always utilize the translate classes provided by Tailwind:

```html
<div class="container" x-data="{ activeSlide: 1, slides: [1, 2, 3] }">
    <div class="relative" style="height:200px;">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="absolute" style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:blue;" x-show="activeSlide === 1"
             x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-1000 transform"
             x-transition:enter-start="-translate-x-5 opacity-0"
             x-transition:enter-end="translate-x-0 opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
            Slide 1
        </div>
        <div class="absolute" style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:orange;" x-show="activeSlide === 2"
             x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-1000 transform"
             x-transition:enter-start="-translate-x-5 opacity-0"
             x-transition:enter-end="translate-x-0 opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
            Slide 2
        </div>
        <div class="absolute" style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:green;" x-show="activeSlide === 3"
             x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-1000 transform"
             x-transition:enter-start="-translate-x-5 opacity-0"
             x-transition:enter-end="translate-x-0 opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-1000"
             x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
             x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
            Slide 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Prev/Next arrow buttons -->
    <div class="box flex flex-space-between flex-middle">
        <button x-on:click="activeSlide = activeSlide === 1 ? slides.length : activeSlide - 1">←</button>
        <button x-on:click="activeSlide = activeSlide === slides.length ? 1 : activeSlide + 1">→</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice how I added a transform class to the `x-transition:enter` and a translate class to `enter-start` and `enter-end`.

You can read more about translate [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/translate)